# If com duas condições

Tags: mysql

Preciso em um select somar um campo, para isto necessito verificar duas    condições, se a moeda for 3 dividir pelo câmbio, se a operação for 18 pegar toda a soma e multiplicar por -1. 
O select que tenho faz a soma verificando a moeda, porém não conseguir colocar duas verificações para tornar negativo quando a operação for 18, pois a operação 18 é cancelamento de registro.

```
 SELECT  SUM(IF(MOEDA=2,(VALOR/CAMBIO), VALOR)) VL FROM banco.CAIXA where DATA= '2018-11-06' AND OPERACAO IN(2,18)
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não esta clara, até tentei responder mas antes é necessário entender essas condições que deverão estar no `if`. Observe que você pode colocar um `if` dentro do próprio `if`, como por exemplo: `IF(pais = 'Brasil', 'R$', IF(pais = 'Estados Unidos', '$', '€')) AS simboloMonetario`

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando o case when, ficaria desta forma.
Exemplo:

```
select
    sum(
    (case when tipo = 2 then (valor/cambio) else valor end)) AS IF1, --se a moeda for 2 faça a divisão pelo cambio
    (case when tipo = 18 then (valor/cambio) else valor end) * -1 as IF2 --se a operação for 18 tenho que além da divisão multiplicar por -1
        from banco.CAIXA;
```

Comment: o problema é que preciso testar mais de uma condição, preciso verificar se a moeda for 2 faça a divisão pelo cambio, e devo levar em consideração que se a operação for 18 tenho que além da divisão multiplicar por -1.

Comment: Alterei a resposta, verifique se atende seu problema.